# What is the angle around a vector from three vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

With three unit vectors $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$, where:

- $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ are strictly on the orthogonal plane of $\vec{u}$;
- in a left-handed coordinate system around $\vec{u}$.

> How to get the angle from $\vec{v}$ to $\vec{w}$?

I know about the dot-product angle:

$$\cos \theta = \frac{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}}{\left|\left|\vec{v}\right|\right|\left|\left|\vec{w}\right|\right|}$$

but that gives the shortest angle despite the left-handed coordinate system.

[image]

Comment: Why should the coordinate system have any effect on the angle?

Comment: The cross product has a $\sin(\theta)$ in it and gives you actually a sign if you rotate $v$ to $w$ over more than $\pi$ or not. If you combine that with the dot-product you can sort out the exact angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A late answer per request of @ronno (comment above). Hope the following is a correct working-out of my hasty comment above...

You may translate all vectors so that they all go through the origin. Assuming that has been done already, we have the following (cross- and dot-product)
$$
v \times w = -|v||w| \sin(\theta) \frac{u}{|u|}\\
(v,w) = |v||w| \cos(\theta)
$$
Getting $\sin(\theta)$ can be done with the component of $u$ which has the largest absolute value (we could take any non-zero component though...). Assuming, as an example, that it is $u_x$ we get
$$
\sin(\theta) = -\frac{|u|}{|v||w|}\frac{(v \times w)_x}{u_x}\\
\cos(\theta) = \frac{(v,w)}{|v||w|}
$$
For a vector with a certain angle $\theta$ with the x-axis, we have
$$
y=\sin(\theta)\\
x=\cos(\theta)
$$
and we can find the angle by
$$
\theta = \text{atan2}(y,x)=\text{atan2}(-\frac{|u|}{|v||w|}\frac{(v \times w)_x}{u_x},\frac{(v,w)}{|v||w|})
$$
which can be simplified to
$$
\theta = -\text{atan2}(|u|\frac{(v \times w)_x}{u_x},(v,w))
$$